# How to pass current_item id in partial after link_to in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a front end from which if clicked on a button **"Rent"**, it will render a `Modal` of a bootstrap in which I need to get `current_item` in order to rent that item. I am currently getting the latest item instead of `current_item`.

**_itemviewer.html.erb**

```
  <% @items.each_with_index do |item, j| %>
     <% if item.user != current_user %>
     <%= link_to 'Rent', '#rentModal', class: 'btn btn-success', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#rentModal"%>
     <%= render partial: "layouts/rent_modal", locals: {current_item: item } %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**inside _rent_modal.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_item, @acquiretime] do |f| %>
  <div class = "add_item_form">            
     <%= f.input :required_time, as: :date, html5: true %>
     <%= f.input :return_time, as: :date, html5: true  %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <%= f.submit 'Add Item', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the question is not clear, what it the lasted item?

Comment: See the answer hope to help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970536/4172515

Comment: @MahmoudSayed, the last added item in the system.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are creating many links to your modal with the same id.

```
 <% @items.each_with_index do |item, j| %>
     <% if item.user != current_user %>
     <%= link_to 'Rent', '#rentModal', class: 'btn btn-success', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#rentModal"%>
     <%= render partial: "layouts/rent_modal", locals: {current_item: item } %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

here's it, for each item you create a new link to your modal with the id `#rentModal` the last modal is the one of the latest item; that may be the cause of being it rendered.

so you may need to create different modals and links ids for each item. 
like the code below.

```
 <% @items.each_with_index do |item, j| %>
     <% if item.user != current_user %>
     <%= link_to 'Rent', "#rentModal_#{j}", class: 'btn btn-success', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#rentModal_#{j}"%>
     <%= render partial: "layouts/rent_modal", locals: {current_item: item, index: j } %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

here you can see that we used `j` to define the Modal id, you need to use that id also in your modal html part, so in your `_rent_modal.html.erb` you need to use the same id for each item and that is why we passed `index` as a local to that partial.. Also you need to wrap your code inside `_rent_modal.html.erb` inside a div with the modal id. you can see how you define a modal [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

Comment: I am getting this in my html. I can see the target took id for each item, but not for href. Any suggestions?
`<a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rentModal_0" href="#rentModal_#{j}">Rent</a>`

And also, I had defined following in my `_rent_modal.html.erb`
`<div class="modal fade" id="rentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="rentModalLabel">`

Comment: ok, I was able to get id after making <%= link_to 'Rent', "#rentModal_#{j}", class: 'btn btn-success', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#rentModal_#{j}"%> where all I did was gave " " instead of ' ', but still not able to give #rentModal_#{index}"  in my _rent_modal.html.erb`